# Using LINQ to output SQL data from two tables into XML

Tags: c#, linq, xml

I am very new to this. Hope someone could help me suggest how to improve the code.

I have two tables where I need to get the SQL data and output it into XML format. I am using LINQ method. Below how the code looks like.

```
    #region Database XML Methods

private static void CreateDatabaseXml(string path)
{
    tbchrDataContext db = new tbchrDataContext();
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        // XML Declaration
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        // XML Root element to 3rd in nest
        new XElement(ns + "WMS",
        new XElement(ns + "Order",
        new XElement(ns + "Header", from a in db.T_ORDER_DETAILs
                                    select new XElement(ns + "RARefNum", a.RARefNum), 
                                    new XElement (ns + "WMSCategory", from b in db.T_ORDER_HEADERs select b.Customer),
                                    new XElement (ns + "CustomerID", from a in db.T_ORDER_DETAILs select a.SupplierName)))) );

    #endregion
    doc.Save(path);
}
```

And below how is the output of XML looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<WMS xmlns="http://blog.cripperz.sg">
  <Order>
    <Header>
      <RARefNum>RASO000001</RARefNum>
      <RARefNum>RASO000001</RARefNum>
      <WMSCategory>ESSVMI</WMSCategory>
      <CustomerID>nVidianVidia</CustomerID>
    </Header>
  </Order>
</WMS>
```

Ultimately I wanted to achieve the below XML, some of the data grab from SQL is from two separate tables in one XML nest / element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WMS>
    <Order>
        <Header>
            <RARefNum>RASO000001</RARefNum>
            <WMSCategory>ESSVMI</WMSCategory>
            <CustomerID>nVidia</CustomerID>
            <CreationDate>2013-12-02 06:29:50</CreationDate>
            <OrderDate>2013-12-02 06:29:50</OrderDate>
            <ExpectedShippedDate>2013-12-02 06:29:50</ExpectedShippedDate>
            <LastShippedDate>2013-12-02 06:29:50</LastShippedDate>
            <CustomerOrderReference>nVidia9338</CustomerOrderReference>
            <CustomerShipmentNo>81475721</CustomerShipmentNo>
            <CustomerSONo>SO982733</CustomerSONo>
            <CustomerInvoiceNo>INV987373</CustomerInvoiceNo>
            <CustomerReference1>nVidia 1</CustomerReference1>
            <CustomerReference2/>
            <WMSReference1>Emp 1</WMSReference1>
            <WMSReference2>Emp 2</WMSReference2>
            <ShipmentNo>IWU997872</ShipmentNo>
            <DocumentNo>KK98764394</DocumentNo>
            <Transportation>
                <Mode>Freight</Mode>
                <VehicleType/>
            </Transportation>
            <Carrier>
                <ID>Fedex</ID>
                <Name>Fedex SG</Name>
                <Address>Changi Singapore</Address>
                <Country/>
                <PostalCode/>
                <Contact>
                    <Sequence/>
                    <Person/>
                    <Email/>
                    <DID/>
                    <Handphone/>
                </Contact>
            </Carrier>
            <Consignee>
                <ID>ABC</ID>
                <Name>ABC Corp</Name>
                <Address>Jurong West, Singapore</Address>
                <Country/>
                <PostalCode/>
                <Contact>
                    <Sequence/>
                    <Person/>
                    <Email/>
                    <DID/>
                    <Handphone/>
                </Contact>
            </Consignee>
            <Containers/>
        </Header>
        <Details>
            <Detail>
                <LineNo>1</LineNo>
                <SKU>SKU0001</SKU>
                <SKUDescription>SKU 0001</SKUDescription>
                <Package>50</Package>
                <OrderedQty>600.000</OrderedQty>
                <PickedQty>600.000</PickedQty>
                <PickedDate>2013-12-02 06:35:09</PickedDate>
                <ShippedQty>600.000</ShippedQty>
                <ShippedDate>2013-12-02 06:35:09</ShippedDate>
                <ManufactoryDate>2013-12-02 06:35:09</ManufactoryDate>
                <ExpiryDate>2014-12-02 06:35:09</ExpiryDate>
                <FIFODate>2013-06-02 06:35:09</FIFODate>
                <CustomerLotRef1>nVidia 2093</CustomerLotRef1>
                <CustomerLotRef2>nVidia 2099</CustomerLotRef2>
                <LineReference1>10</LineReference1>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <LineNo>2</LineNo>
                <SKU>SKU0002</SKU>
                <SKUDescription>SKU 0002</SKUDescription>
                <Package>50</Package>
                <OrderedQty>100.000</OrderedQty>
                <PickedQty>100.000</PickedQty>
                <PickedDate>2013-12-02 06:35:09</PickedDate>
                <ShippedQty>100.000</ShippedQty>
                <ShippedDate>2013-12-02 06:35:09</ShippedDate>
                <ManufactoryDate>2013-12-02 06:35:09</ManufactoryDate>
                <ExpiryDate>2014-12-02 06:35:09</ExpiryDate>
                <FIFODate>2013-06-02 06:35:09</FIFODate>
                <CustomerLotRef1>nVidia 2193</CustomerLotRef1>
                <CustomerLotRef2>nVidia 2199</CustomerLotRef2>
                <LineReference1>10</LineReference1>
            </Detail>
        </Details>
    </Order>
</WMS>
```

Is there a better way to code it?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is for this use XML serialization. Check the [Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Simply what you have to do is arrange a class structure according to your XML required and then create your object and use serialization to create your XML.

If you need more help let me know I can help you.